# "0 records imported" when importing JSON file to MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

When I follow the `Table Data Import Wizard` I can see that it has successfully parsed the JSON file in the preview it provides. However, at the end, I see "0 records imported". This happens even with a simple JSON file, for example with contents `{"name":"Name"}`. I am using MySQL Workbench and server version 8.0.33.

Schema properties:

[image]

JSON file's contents:

[image]

Successfully parsing the JSON file:

[image]

However:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps showing the target table definition and the contents of the file you're trying to import will help people help you.

Comment: The table is constructed automatically as its columns are inferred from the JSON file.

Comment: Pasting textual info as text is better than using  images.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with char format of JSON file. So you may convert JSON into csv and test. Same situation with me, but in my case table has an amount column as float(8,2)  and providing JSON file as `[ {..., "amount": 800.00, ...},{...}, ...]`. due to value 800.00 my record does not inserted in table from JSON file, so i just provide "amount":800 without decimal point and it worked for me.